# click event for node wicket

Tags: treeview, tree, wicket

Hi I have a treeview populated with various data (dynamic). Is there a way to add a lister to the nodes and then retrieve what has been clicked? Thanks.

```
add(new AjaxLink("expandAll") {
    @Override public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) { 
        getTree().getTreeState().expandAll();
        getTree().updateTree(target);
        System.out.println("Click");
} });
```

This is what i have so far for adding a listener, all this does is expand the tree.

Comment: Okay, but this isn't a node of the tree, this is just a link added to the tree. Where do you create the nodes for the tree? That's where you need to add something to get a notification of a node being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `AjaxEventBehavior` to each node that is triggered by the `onclick` event.

(If you add some code to the question, I can be more specific than that.)

Comment: add(new AjaxLink("expandAll")
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)
            {
                getTree().getTreeState().expandAll();
                getTree().updateTree(target);
                System.out.println("Click");
            }
        });   This is what i have so far for adding a listener, all this does is expand the tree. I do not know how to add it to a dynamic node. Thanks